# Inferring a distribution from a sample

Tags: distributions, estimation, inference, sample, density-estimation

I would like to know more about the general process of finding an approximate distribution to fit a given sample. Or, more accurately, given a random variable $X$ with unknown distribution, and a sample $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ from it, find a good distribution to model that variable.

Somewhat formally, I want to find a distribution function $p$ that minimizes $E[-\log(p(X))]$, given only the sample, and not $X$. Of course, in general, assumptions may have to be made about $X$ in order for this problem to be well defined.

Does this process have a name? What methods are typically used for it?

Here are two examples of possible methods, to illustrate what I'm thinking of:

- One simple method would be to assume $X$ is Gaussian, and use Maximum
  Likelihood Estimation (or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2677365/537420) superior method).
- Another method would be to replace each sample point by a Gaussian centered 
  around that point, and take the normalized sum of all the Gaussians as the 
  model distribution.

See my comments to better understand my question.

Comment: You don't describe a workable procedure, because you haven't posited any connection at all between $E[-X\log(p(X))]$ and the sample except that the distribution *could* have produced the sample.  That information alone is next to useless and it leads to an even worse solution. Therefore I doubt this process has any name.

Comment: @whuber As I wrote in my question, assumptions may have to be made about X in order to get a well defined problem. The process does have a name (I found it in the meantime); it's called Density Estimation.

Comment: @whuber Additionally, if the domain of the random variable is finite, the problem makes sense without any assumption on $X$ beyond the principle of indifference. For example, if the set is $\{0,1\}$, then even with an empty sample, there is a solution: assign a probability of one half to $0$, and to $1$.

Comment: I don't like the statement a ``random variable and a sample from it", that is an incorrect statement.  A random variable has  distribution and you can draw samples from its distribution

Comment: Minimizing E[−log(p(X)) is equivalent to minimizing KL(q || p), where q is the distribution of X.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Density Estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_estimation) is roughly what I was looking for. Note there is a slight difference between finding the most likely distribution, and finding the distribution that best models $X$ given our knowledge. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2676965/) question for an example.

Comment: This post might be better suited as a clarification to the question, because it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @whuber It's a partial answer, since it gives the name of the "process of finding an approximate distribution to fit a given sample".

Comment: In that sense it only clarifies what you were trying to ask.  "Density estimation" is a broad answer to an even broader, overly vague question, so I'm only trying to suggest that to make this thread useful on this site you consider (a) clarifying the question and (b) making this reply more specific.

Comment: @whuber Why do you think the question is overly vague? Estimating a distribution given a sample is a common and important problem. Also, my answer includes a link to the Wikipedia article, which mentions specific techniques that can be used to solve this problem.

Comment: There are a great many ways to do it, based on different assumptions, different purposes, and different kinds of data.  It isn't in the least evident that your question seeks a density estimator: it is phrased in a way that sounds like it is asking for a maximum entropy solution. (You don't even assume the distribution *has* a density!) Density estimation doesn't respond to your specific request to optimize the particular functional of the distribution that you mention.

Comment: @whuber I would love to know about the many ways to do it, their assumptions, purposes, and kinds of data. If someone gives a better answer, I'll accept theirs. The objective I mention is the natural one to minimize. It expresses the minimization of the surprise from seing new sample points from $X$. Of course, in practice, it's often too difficult to minimize this objective, so other heuristics are used.

Comment: There are general solutions to this problem: generative models. People who marked my question as unclear probably either didn't understand my question, or are not used to abstractions and/or generalizations (two pillars of the mathematical approach). Marking a question as unclear because there are different ways to solve the described problem depending on the situation doesn't make sense. Additionally, as I said, there are practical general solutions to the problem of density estimation.

Answer (score 2):

As [whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber) correctly points out in the comment on your question, the objective function you are seeking to optimise does not depend on the sample, and so it does not give a workable procedure that would use the sample in the estimation.  Also, you say you want to *minimise* your objective function, but that is trivial since any point-mass distribution gives $\log p(X) = 0$ with probability one.  I assume that what you meant to do is to *maximise* the analogous sample quantity that would estimate the quantity you have described.  If that is correct, then I describe this below.

---

**A related problem:** Letting $\boldsymbol{p} \equiv (p_1, ..., p_n)$ be the probabilities of the sample points $x_1, ..., x_n$, suppose you want to maximise the objective function:

$$F(\boldsymbol{p}) \equiv- \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i p_i \log p_i.$$

This is the sample estimate of the function you described in your question.  Maximising this function is a variation on the problem of finding the maximum-entropy distribution, except that you have an additional term $x_i$ in the sum and so this is a form of *maximum-weighted-entropy*.

Anyway, this objective function is a concave function with partial derivatives given by:

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial p_k} (\boldsymbol{p}) = - \frac{x_k}{n} (1 + \log p_k).$$

The maximising point $\hat{\boldsymbol{p}}$ occurs under the conditions $x_1 (1 + \log \hat{p}_1) = ... = x_n (1 + \log \hat{p}_n)$.  So, setting $\upsilon \equiv x_k (1 + \log \hat{p}_k)$ yields the solution form:

$$\hat{p}_k = \exp \Big( \frac{\upsilon  - x_k}{x_k} \Big),$$

where $\upsilon$ can be obtained by solving the constraint equation $\sum \hat{p}_k = 1$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it's not what I'm looking for. The additional $X$ was a mistake, I fixed it now. You're probably right that I'm not expressing the problem correctly, but that is part of my problem. I want to solve the following scenario: Imagine someone has a distribution, but doesn't show it to you. They only give you a sample drawn from it. Then, they are going to give you an additional sample point X, but before they show it to you, you have to come up with a distribution such that $E[-\log(p(X))]$ is minimized. That is the problem I want to solve.

Comment: "Also, you say you want to minimise your objective function, but that is trivial since any point-mass distribution gives $\log p(X) = 0$ with probability one." Wouldn't it give minus infinity? And that is not the objective function I have (nor the one I had before I edited my question).

Comment: You get $\log p = - \infty$ only when $p=0$.  But if you have a point-mass distribution then *with probability one* the point that occurs is the one with probability one, so you have $p=1$ and $\log p =0$.

Comment: If the inclusion of the additional $X$ was a mistake, then it sounds like what you're looking for is a maximum-entropy distribution.  It might be worth having a look at some papers on this and then coming back to the problem.  This would probably help you reformulate it a bit more clearly.

Comment: Generative models are the practical solutions to this problem, so there is in fact a workable procedure.

Comment: I want to minimize E[−log(p(X))] on X, not only on the provided sample. So a point mass distribution does not work.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean when you say you want to minimise this function "on $X$".  The function is an expected value, which depends on the underlying distribution of $X$.

Comment: I meant that I don't only want to minimize it on the sample. So I want to minimize E[-log(p(X))], where X has an unknown distribution, of which we only have a sample S. That's why, in general, a point mass distribution wouldn't work. Have a look at the problem generative models (GANs, VAEs, etc) solve.

Comment: You can also look at the KL divergence (whose minimization is equivalent to minimizing E[-log(p(X))] in this case).

Comment: @StephaneBersier: I'm afraid you still have not articulated a clear optimisation problem (and multiple experts on this site have closed your question as unclear).  I suggest you write out your desired optimisation problem formally, in the language $\hat{F}(y) \equiv \min_{x \in \mathscr{X}} F(x|y)$, where you clearly specify the variable $x$ over which you are minimising, the domain $\mathscr{X}$ over which the function is being minimised, and any other variable $y$ on which the function depends.  Until you do this, it is not clear to me what your optimisation problem actually is.

Comment: $\hat{d}_\mathscr{D}(S, P) \equiv \min_{d \in \mathscr{D}} E_{P \sim \mathscr{P}|S}[E_{x \sim P}[-\log(d(x))]]$, where $\mathscr{D}$ is a subset of the set of distributions over some set $T$ (so $d$ is a distribution), $S$ is a multiset of points from $T$, $\mathscr{P}$ is a possibly improper prior over $\mathscr{D}$, and $\mathscr{P}|S$ is the marginal over $\mathscr{P}$ that assumes that $S$ is a sample drawn from $P$ (not sure if I'm using the proper terms and notation here). By abuse of notation, $d$ is also used for the PDF (or PMF) of $d$. Hopefully there are no mistakes.

Comment: Let me know if that works for you (sorry for all the intermediate versions).

Comment: Actually, I think it's a posterior, not a marginal.

Comment: @Stephane: Okay, so I think there are a lot of problems with this specification, and it doesn't seem to accord at all with your original question.  For example, you are now talking about taking the logarithm of the distribution $d$ of $X$, rather than the logarithm of $X$.  You condition on values in $S$, which I'm assuming are supposed to be your sample data, but you have specified them as distributions in $T$.  It is unclear why you have introduced a prior at all, let alone one that operates on $X$, which would suggest that $X$ is a model parameter.

Comment: I think I'm going to end these comments here, and just leave this for you to think about.

Comment: I did make some notation changes to make it clearer. In the original question, I used $p$ instead of $d$ (my comment is self-contained, though). And I haven't specified $S$ as a distribution in $T$. I said "$S$  is a multiset of points from $T$". In other words, $S$ is a "multi-sub-set" of $T$. And I never defined any $X$! I have a small $x$, and $\mathscr{P}$ which is a prior over $\mathscr{D}$. Math needs to be read carefully.